# Trying to fit data into sine cosine curve fit using scipy

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, curve-fitting

I am new to signal processing in python.
Here I am trying fit data to sine cosine curve using the equation -
A * np.sin(x) + B * np.cos(x) + C.

here is the snippet of the code

```
def func(x, A, B, C):
    return A * np.sin(x) + B * np.cos(x) + C

p0 = 0, 25, 10
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)

times = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], num=21)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', color='red', label="data")
plt.plot(times, func(times, *popt), '--', color='blue', label="optimized data")
# plt.plot(x, func(x, *popt), '--', color='blue', label="optimized data")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I am getting below output (in image)

[image]

Could anyone help me spotting the mistake or any suggestion with the code

Comment: you need to scale on `x`, so the equation should be like: `A * sin(S * x) + B * cos(S*x) + C`, where S is a scale factor

Comment: Thank you for the response, but honestly since i am very new to this , i did not understand the meaning scalar factor or like where can I study regarding same

Comment: Please joint the data instead of graph only. Without numerial one cannot reproduce what you did and check. The comment of Marat is a key. This is a four parameters regression problem A, B, C and the period (or frequency) which is missing in your model.